# Connection refused when running Laravel artisan command with Docker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm running Laravel 5.4 in Docker. This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    container_name: laravel_app
    image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:ubuntu-16.04
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      docker: 'true'
      WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/app/public'
      WEB_NO_CACHE_PATTERN: '\.(.*)$$'
      working_dir: '/app'
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - 8889:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'dev'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'dev'
      MYSQL_USER: 'dev'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'dev'
```

This is the relevant part of my `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=dev
DB_USERNAME=dev
DB_PASSWORD=dev
```

I am able to see the Laravel welcome page - that side of things works. But when I run `php artisan migrate` I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = dev and table_name = migrations)

I have tried fiddling with the `host` and `port` parameters in the `.env` file.

Comment: Who invokes the docker compose command? You (manually) or some kind of script, jenkins, travis, gitlab-ci...

Comment: Me manually: `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Remove port-exposing, mariadb:latest sets it in its Dockerfile: **This image exposes the standard MySQL port (3306)...**

Comment: God bless you @Kyslik

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First edit your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - 8889:3306
```

After that set the correct DB port in `.env`.

Your DB port is wrong. You are trying to connect the exposed port inside the docker. In this case you should use `DB_PORT=3306` in your `.env`.

Comment: This is a typo question it should be removed, since OP failed to read https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/.

Comment: If that rule was universally applied, SO would be a third of its current size. I'm not saying that's necessarily a bad thing...

Comment: that's the issue we are facing! thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 46):

this worked for me:
put the name of my mysql container instead of 127.0.0.1

```
NAME CONTAINERS

project-db --> container mysql
project-app --> container laravel

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=project-db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   This worked for me.  Opened up Docker and copied the name of my mysql container:  my-ap_mysql_1 and put it as the DB_HOST.

Comment: That's weird, it works but cost me days of searching for solutions. Thanks for saving me more days of googling :D

Comment: I would have never figured this out had I not seen this. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know why this worked for you? It didn't work for me and I was wondering if there's any documentation

Comment: This may not be the actual solution of question which OP asked, but this is solution of one of the most common mistake

Answer (score 6):

After 5 hours researching I found this quote in comments:

> Remove port-exposing, mariadb:latest sets it in its Dockerfile: This image exposes the standard MySQL port (3306)...

This mean you MUST use port 3306 in `.env` of each Laravel projects, either you define port for Mysql(or mariaDB).

This mean in host only port 3306 connect your Laravel to database.

Comment: I also found this one true for me while using mysql:latest. Despite setting a custom port, only 3306 works.

Answer (score 4):

Try change port to 3306 and use DB_HOST=localhost to yourdomain.com(your IP)

And don't forget Sudo  Clear cache and config cache

```
DB_HOST=My_ip_for_virtual_machine (yourdomain.com)
sudo docker-compose exec app php artisan config:clear
sudo docker-compose exec app php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set the DB port like in @kotapeter's answer, you can instead invoke artisan through docker by running:

```
$ docker exec -it <name of container> php artisan migrate
```

Looking at your `docker-compose.yml`, your container could be `laravel_app_app_1` but you can check this by running `docker ps`

Comment: how you can do that?
we have the connection refused problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did try to set container name in env file, it works great in http requests, but in console I had issue for resolving container name(in my case its `mysql`)

I added container name and point it to `127.0.0.1` in windows host file

```
127.0.0.1 mysql
```